# How can I get the sums of all the integers in a row of an SQL table with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently making an attendance website. The data for attendance is stored like this...

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  Name  |  12/20/16  |  12/21/16  |  12/23/16  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|Person1 |  1         | 0          |  1         |
|Person2 |  0         | 1          |  0         |
|Person3 |  1         | 1          |  1         |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

If a person was there, then the date column for their row is marked as a "1". If they weren't there, then the date column for their row is marked as a "0".

I am trying to make a readout of how many days they were present.

How can I get a sum of all the values in the date columns for that specific person's row in PHP?

EDIT: I understand that it is a bad way of formatting the data. This is per the owners request. They have their mind set on it and won't listen to reason. They are thinking of SQL as an Excel file.

Comment: That is a terrible way of recording attendance. Refactor your database and use a seperate table for the dates attended i.e. Person table and an Attendance table. This will also make your query easier. read https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relational-databases-for-dummies--net-30244

Comment: The problem is with your data. The dates shouldn't be in columns. A database isn't a spreadsheet. The dates should be in rows.

Comment: I understand that it is a bad way of formatting the data. This is per the owners request. They have their mind set on it and won't listen to reason. They are thinking of SQL as an Excel file.

Comment: I agree your DB need to be redesign, but to answer your question I will say you have to go through all columns adding the values for each row you read from the DB. so `SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE NAME = 'Person1'` will give you the row, then you read each column in the result of the query, adding the values.

Comment: Why are the owners dictating the software design? It doesn't matter how they think of it, because you can display it on the frontend however you want.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I can't believe that I didn't think of that. I guess the simplest answers are the best ones. Thanks!

Comment: @kyle He wants his phpMyAdmin to look like that when he accesses it.

Comment: @CarlFlood -- make a view and change his user to only be able to view that view -- then he can see it the way he wants.

Comment: while @DIEGOCARRASCAL solution would work, you are executing 30 queries for each employee, expect to hear a lot of complaints about the app being unresponsive.

Comment: I didn't intent it to be an answer because there is a lot to improve on it, is just the process to extract a single "person" data, I believe the idea will be to create a single query with all the "persons" and then run on the data... It was just a basic analysis of the requirement. :) But well I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: @e4c5 I decided to make one query to get all of the data of that user, then process it with a for loop, incrementing the count each time, then return that data.

Comment: @Hogan he wants everything done on his servers, and has access to the root account. Very annoying employer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so with the help of some people in the comments, I have put together a working function to accomplish what I needed.

```
$ppl = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Attendance2016 WHERE name = '" . getSessionVal("Name") . "'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ppl);
$loopMax = count($row);

$currentAtttendance = 0;

for($x = 0; $x < $loopMax; $x++){
    if($row[$x] === "0"){
        continue;
    }else if($row[$x] === "1"){
        $currentAtttendance = $currentAtttendance + 1;
    }
}

return $currentAtttendance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't refactor the database to work the only way to do this is

```
 SELECT name, `12/20/16`+`12/21/16`+`12/23/16` as days_attended
 FROM tablename
```

and yes every time you add a column you have to change your query.

You could make a dynamic query -- use the above as a template as to what that dynamic query would look like.

But you REALLY should refactor the database and make a **view** for your user to make them happy.

This is exactly why views exist.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename` and remember the first column is the name and the rest are dates and then no changes needed in the query. But yes, they will have to limit the amount of columns creating tables for the year or something like that, other wise with time the tables will grow... (+- 30 columns per month)